# Python - argsort sorting incorrectly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, np.argsort

What is the problem? Where am I doing wrong?

I am new to Python and I could not find the problem. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

**The code is**

```
import numpy as np
users = [["Richard", 18],["Sophia", 16],["Kelly", 3],["Anna", 15],["Nicholas", 17],["Lisa", 2]]
users = np.array(users)
print(users[users[:, 1].argsort()])
```

**Output should be**

```
[['Lisa' '2']
['Kelly' '3']
['Anna' '15']
['Sophia' '16']
['Nicholas' '17']
['Richard' '18']]
```

**But output is**

```
[['Anna' '15']
['Sophia' '16']
['Nicholas' '17']
['Richard' '18']
['Lisa' '2']
['Kelly' '3']]
```

Comment: given the input list of lists `users`, what is the reason for using `numpy`? Why not just sort the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers are being interpreted as strings (so '15' comes before '2', like 'ae' comes before 'b').  The fact that in the output, you see things like '15' with single quotes around it, is a clue to this.

In order to create a numpy array which has a mixture of data types (strings for the names, ints for the numbers), you can create the array this way, specifying the data type as `object`:

`users = np.array(users, dtype=object)`

That will give the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When converting it to a `np.array` the integers are converted to strings and strings get sorted differently than numbers.

You could sort the lists first and then convert it to an array (if you really want that).

```
users = [["Richard", 18],["Sophia", 16],["Kelly", 3],["Anna", 15],["Nicholas", 17],["Lisa", 2]]
users_sorted = sorted(users, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(users_sorted)

[['Lisa', 2], ['Kelly', 3], ['Anna', 15], ['Sophia', 16], ['Nicholas', 17], ['Richard', 18]]
```

Comment: Do you think OP wants second element to be converted to `str` or it is just unwanted side-effect of converting to numpy array?

Comment: I think it is unwanted, that's why I wrote "convert it afterwards to an array if you really want that"

Comment: No, in your result everything is `str` in the numpy array, e.g. `['Lisa' '2']`.  `'2'`, not `2`. You sort the list and then convert the sorted list to array.

Comment: yes, because of converting it to a `np.array`. I think with the given data, lists are more suited than `np.array's`. I just tried to stay close to OP's attempt (his result are also strings only), but I get your point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you don't want to change the dtype:

```
print(users[users[:, 1].astype(float).argsort()])
```

It should give you the result you are looking for.
The answer given by slothrop is enough as an explanation

Answer (score 0):

If there is a possibility of multiple people having the same number you probably want to use [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort) instead of [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort), to first sort on the number and then by name:

```
import numpy as np

users = [["Richard", 18], ["Sophia", 16], ["Kelly", 3], ["Bob", 15], ["Anna", 15], ["Nicholas", 17], ["Lisa", 2]]
users = np.array(users, dtype=object)
sorted_users = users[np.lexsort((users[:,0], users[:,1]))]
print(sorted_users)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Lisa' 2]
 ['Kelly' 3]
 ['Anna' 15]
 ['Bob' 15]
 ['Sophia' 16]
 ['Nicholas' 17]
 ['Richard' 18]]
```

The equivalent without using `numpy` would be like this:

```
users = [["Richard", 18], ["Sophia", 16], ["Kelly", 3], ["Anna", 15], ["Nicholas", 17], ["Lisa", 2]]
sorted_users = sorted(users, key=lambda user: (user[1], user[0]))
print(sorted_users)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Lisa', 2], ['Kelly', 3], ['Anna', 15], ['Bob', 15], ['Sophia', 16], ['Nicholas', 17], ['Richard', 18]]
```